# Need help getting table from HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I had been successfully pulling mutual fund performance data from Marketwatch.com using the following code:

```
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim C As Long
Dim Z As Long


For Z = 1 To 35

    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset((37 + (Z * 10)), 0).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    Exit For
    Else
    End If
Dim oHTML       As Object
Dim oTable      As Object
Dim x           As Long
Dim Y           As Long
Dim vData       As Variant

Set oHTML = CreateObject("HTMLFile")

With CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
.Open "GET", "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/vfinx", False
.send
oHTML.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
End With

For Each oTable In oHTML.Getelementsbytagname("table")
If oTable.classname = "fundstable" Then
    ReDim vData(1 To oTable.Rows.Length, 1 To oTable.Rows(1).Cells.Length)

        For x = 1 To UBound(vData)
        For Y = 1 To UBound(vData, 2)
            vData(x, Y) = oTable.Rows(x - 1).Cells(Y - 1).innertext
        Next Y
        Next x

    With ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
    .Resize(UBound(vData), UBound(vData, 2)).Value = vData
    End With
Exit For
End If
Next oTable

Next Z
```

Unfortunately, Marketwatch has added a Captcha to stop bots (i.e. me) from scraping their data. I don't know of anyway around this, so I figured I'd try another site.

I looked at Morningstar:  http://performance.morningstar.com/fund/performance-return.action?t=VFINX&region=usa&culture=en_US

It appears that the table I want on that page would be:  "table.r_table3 width955px  print97" or just "r_table3 width955px  print97", but neither one seems to work for me.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded by javascript and won't be available via XMLHTTP request as scripts won't have run to load content.

You can use that second link, for example, with IE and introduce a wait to ensure info is loaded. I show getting the table with that class name at index 1. You can change the index here:

```
ele.item(1).outerHTML
```

So, for the next table use `clipboard.SetText ele.item(2).outerHTML` .

You can also loop the `.Length` of `ele` to get each table but ensure you write out to a different cell when you paste:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To ele.Length-1
    clipboard.SetText  ele.item(i).outerHTML
   'Etc   
Next
```

---

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, clipboard As Object
    Dim ele As Object, ws As Worksheet, t As Date, tableCount As Long
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://performance.morningstar.com/fund/performance-return.action?t=VFINX&region=usa&culture=en_US"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            t = Timer
            Do
                DoEvents
                On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = .querySelectorAll(".r_table3.print97")
                tableCount = ele.Length
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While tableCount < 3

            If Not ele Is Nothing Then
                clipboard.SetText ele.item(1).outerHTML
                clipboard.PutInClipboard
                ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
            End If
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

[image]

Comment: OK - that's working - Thanks!  But I actually wanted the next table down on that page. So I changed ".r_table3.print97" to ".r_table3.width955px.print97"  and I start getting a Run-time error '424': Object required.  Forgive my newbie question, but I thought we already declared that object, so I'm not understanding why switching tables is causing this error. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Use clipboard.SetText ele.item(2).outerHTML

Comment: Instead of  clipboard.SetText ele.Item(1).outerHTML?   (If so, that's not working for me)  Still getting the same 424 error

Comment: It you can get table 1 fine then you should be able to get the next. Insert debug.print ele.length before the failing line. Then Ctrl + G to check what value is printed. Also, check your code is as in my link above. You can also increase Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10

Comment: The only difference in my code is I'm using .r_table3.width955px.print97 instead of .r_table3.print97.  The debug produces just the number 1... not sure where that is coming from!

Comment: With that change in selector your table is now at index 0 This means you can just use querySelector as shown in following: https://pastebin.com/8EjacfnA

Comment: That did it!  Thank you very much!!  Only other question - any way to do it without a window opening?  i.e. just work in the background... I plan on adding this to other code to pull that table on many funds, and don't want a new window opening each time.  Thanks again!

Comment: ie.visible = False You can't see it. If you don't want any browser opening then consider whether API is offered and use XMLHTTP.

Comment: Not sure how to get the API, but I thought that wouldn't work due to Javascript

Comment: API if available won’t have that problem. It serves up everything in the response.

Comment: You would need to research if an API is made available